# Copy Sheet from one Workbook to another workbook by using workbook.open

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open two workbooks then copying the first sheet of one workbook to last sheet of another workbook. But getting "copy method of worksheet failed" error. could you please help me to sort out the issue.

```
Sub copysheets()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wba As Workbook
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim lrow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

lrow = wb.Sheets("Target").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 6 To lrow

Set wba = Workbooks.Open(wb.Sheets("Target").Range("D3"))

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(wb.Sheets("Target").Range("A" & i))


wbk.Sheets(1).copy After:=wba.Sheets(wba.Sheets.Count)

wbk.Close savechanges:=False

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Start by moving `Set wba = Workbooks.Open(wb.Sheets("Target").Range("D3"))` outside the loop.

Comment: I have made changes but still getting same error

Comment: My Code is correct only.. I am getting the error sicne one of the file had first sheet as Veryhidden status.. once I did the modification to  that sheet my code is working properly.